# best way to rewind a variable at 1?

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.0

I have an array with 12 entries.

When doing `12+1`, I want to get the entry `1` of the array

When doing `12+4`, I want to get the entry `4` of the array

etc...

I'm done with

```
cases_to_increment.each do |k|
  if k > 12
    k = k-12
  end

  self.inc(:"case#{k}", 1)
end
```

I found a solution with modulo

```
k = 13%12 = 1
k = 16%12 = 4
```

I like the modulo way but 12%12 return 0 and I need only numbers between 1..12

There is a way to do that without condition ?

Comment: `(x % 12) + 1`. However, modulo is a highly inefficient function. your condition is much faster.

Comment: It looks much better if you write `k -= 12 if k > 12`.

Comment: Can you give an example input and output you want to see..so that we can offer better solution too..

Comment: @njzk2: In my benchmark (using the module) it was 0.164313 vs. 0.156668 (module vs. array access) for 50000 x 24 accesses (ruby 2.0) so the difference is negligible and modulo works for numbers > 24 too.

Comment: s/array access/if/ - sorry for the mistake.

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka : my experience is more in python and java, so there may be something about ruby (in python i obtain 0.0449 vs 0.0396 for % vs if)

Comment: I was quite surprised/interested to see alleged large difference between modulo and conditional assignment, and confirmed it is not the case in Ruby benchmarks. In this case (and quite often in Ruby), style-versus-optimisation, I would suggest choosing the most expressive, easy-to-read implementation, because the difference in performance here is negligable. What is best may then be a matter of opinion, both options in OP work for me; I'd probably pick modulo purely as a personal thing.

Answer (score 0):

You almost had the solution there yourself. Instead of a simple modulo, try:

`index = (number % 12) + 1`

Edit: njzk2 is correct, modulo is a very expensive function if you are using it with a value that is not a power of two. If, however, your total number of elements (the number you are modulo-ing with) is a power of 2, the calculation is essentially free.

Comment: "if you are using it with a value that is not a power of two" this is true for JITed languages or statically compiled ones when this knowledge is present during compilation time. However if it is not a modulo instruction is used anyway which have a fixed latency and it is not efficient to check if number is power of 2 anyway as the flushing pipeline would be too expensive. Ruby interpreter neither perform JIT nor compilation so speed of `10 % 2` is the same as `10 % 3` (confirmed by benchmark) - and the cost of interpreter is much higher then `div` instruction anyway.